# Kali Login Screen

Tags: kali-linux

I just installed Kali 1.1.0, and changed `gnome-fallback` to `gnome`. 
Is there a way for me to change the login/lock screen?
I would like to change the background, but also the appearance

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want a completely different lockscreen

Comment: Kali Linux is intended for penetration testing, and not for every day use.  I'd suggest you use a different distro for everyday use.  In addition, your question as it is is not answerable.  Please provide the Gnome version number currently installed.

Comment: i just made a short video how to change it on kali rolling , works fine. check it out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahxDU07x9zI

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% about older versions, but in later versions, you can simply goto the top-right of the workspace desktop (where you would access the quick info for Wi-Fi). Click the wrench/settings icon, and then enter settings (you can do this through any method you're comfortable with). Finally, select the "background" icon in settings. Settings window is akin to Windows Control Panel, and going to Display, then Background.

So check if you can goto All Settings, look for a Background or similar option, and changer the lock screen and desktop separately.

I apologize if this does not work on 1.1, but I wanted to mention, Kali may be more difficult or work-intensive, for everyday use, unless your everyday use is fairly simple and you don't mind occasional commands. It is a great distro to begin getting the hang on Linux, to perform tasks and understand the CLI better. But as mentioned, it is not an optimal Linux distro to attempt to use for every day use. Its not really configured for it and you will need to learn certain commands you will commonly deal with.

It still mounts drives and plays files w/o problem, so if you are using it to watch a movie or listen to music and browse the web, it'll with fine. Not optimal, but there's nothing actually "wrong" with doing it. Other versions can be easier to acclimate to though.

Also, GNOME is basically your desktop system. As you found out, changing this option on the lock screen only changes your environment. It does not pertain to the lock screen itself though, in terms of directly controlling it by switching that drop down option and selecting GNOME or anything else. You would need to manually set the bg pic through commands or by searching for settings.

Hope any of that helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

Changing and configuring the login wallpaper for Kali 2.0 is three step process.
I am not sure if this is helpful for the Kali 1.0 users though.
Once in the terminal

1. Find the resolution of the current login image. To do this you could use the below command.

   `eog /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/KaliLogin.png`

   In the image-viewer look at te bottom left corner to see the resolution.
2. Once you get the resolution, make sure that your replacement image is of this size and more importantly in the png format. Then move your image to replace the existing image by using the below command.

   `mv /path/to/your/image/image_name.png /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/KaliLogin.png`
3. This is an optional step. Reboot the computer to see if the new image fits perfectly into the login screen. If not, run the below command in terminal

   `gnome /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`

   This will open (in the text editor) the cascade style sheet which helps you set the background image settings for the login screen. In this file look for the below lines

   `#lockDialogGroup {
   background: #2e3436 url(KaliLogin.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
   }`

Change the `background-size` to `contain`. Save and close the css file and reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the same, I don't like the big 'KALI LINUX' screen that pops up at the coffee shop ;)

find a new image you want to use; look in 
/usr/share/images/desktop-base/

get the full path and append the name of the image you want to use to the command as shown bellow.

```
sudo gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename --type string /usr/share/images/desktop-base/lines-grub-1920x1080.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You may alter the file 10-desktop-base-settings to point to a different image.
location = /usr/share/gdm/dconf/10-desktop-base-settings

You may also alter the image directly.
location = /usr/share/images/desktop-base

These are the default images for the login screen. alter the one that applies to your resolution.
kali-wallpaper_1024x768.png
kali-wallpaper_1280x1024.png
kali-wallpaper_1280x800.png
kali-wallpaper_1600x1200.png
kali-wallpaper_1920x1080.png
kali-wallpaper_1920x1200.png

The default login user image file. 
location = /usr/share/desktop-base/kali-dragon.png

Answer (score 0):

If someone is searching for it after 2020, everything is easier now!
At least on my version `Linux sec 5.4.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1kali1 (2020-02-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

They have adopted `LightDM GTK+ Greeter` for support login screen.

So you just need to search it in the menu, authenticate and change your background. Also, there's an option now for set a photo for login profile and a lot of other options.